# How to automatically make copies of columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Everyday I have to take the raw data which has more than 40 columns and increasing number of rows (right now 2,5 millions) and prepare it according to a certain format.

Lets assume that I have 5 columns in the raw data:

**name - surname - year - country - gender**

what I need is:

**surname - gender - country**

which means I need just some of the columns and in a different order.

Comment: with your problem, you should using record marco feature of Excel which can help you to do repeated-action quickly

Comment: How do you know which columns you need? I mean, is it only those with certain names, or in a certain column position? Such as ColumnA, C, F and K etc

Comment: If order of 5 above columns is fixed, you can use index 1,2,3 .. instead of A,B,C. if not, create a simple while loop to find out column index (assume that column header is fixed with "name - surname - year ..")

Comment: Hello Dave and Dai, 
Yes the columns are fixed, for example column B of the raw data sheet always goes to column A of the final sheet.

Comment: How do you put 2.5 million rows into Excel? Are you using Power Pivot?

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the last action by clicking Repeat on the Quick Access Toolbar. Keyboard shortcut Press CTRL+Y or F4.

Answer (score 0):

Where do the 2.5 million rows originate? Not Excel, because an Excel sheet can only have 1,048,576 rows.

If you use the data model in Excel 2010 or 2013, you can handle more than Excel's limit, but the data won't be visible in a sheet. You can use Power Query to import large amounts of data (more than the Excel sheet limit) from different sources into the data model. Power Query can also be used to transform the source data, for example remove columns and change the order of columns.

You can download Power Query as an Excel add-in [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=39379). It works with most editions of  Excel 2010 and 2013 and will be built into Excel 2016.

Comment: I have checked and you are right, the 2,5 M data was something else.
The sheet I'm talking about has around 300.000 rows.

Comment: Power Query is still the best way to go (as far as I'm concerned). It's a free download from Microsoft and it is very powerful to connect to data sources and re-shape your data to your requirements. I added a download link to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your illustrative raw data of 5 columns is in `Sheet1`, Row 1 contains the headers **name - surname - year - country - gender**, and the data begins in Row 2.

Let's now put the 3 headers you want in Row 1 of `Sheet2`, put in the following formula in A2, and drag it down/across:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A2:$E2,MATCH(A$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1,0))
```

This is a horizontal lookup that, for each row, searches across every column to return the value in the right column.

If this takes too long (sounds like calculation time matters to you), you can just look up (`MATCH`) the correct column once, then `index` off it. Add an extra row of 3 values in, say, row 2 of `Sheet2` with `=MATCH(A$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1,0)` (and let's assume your data in `Sheet1` now starts in row 3), now put `=INDEX(Sheet1$A3:$E3,A$2)` in `Sheet2!A3` and fill across + down.